# How remove a remote commit without removing the changes

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I accidentally added a commit with the wrong user name and pushed it to the remote. Now I want to remove that particular commit but I want to keep the changes.

Is there a way to do this? I tried `git reset` but that would mean I would lose the changes. Is there a way to squash the commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With git it's possible to squash previous commits into one. What I would suggest is for you to add another commit. And squash the the commit with wrong user with the last commit you added.

Let assume you have the following commits from the `git log --oneline -2`.

- xf71a11 - last commit
- 1a9ddqw - commit done with the wrong user

To squash the commit done with wrong user you should use the git command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

which will open up your editor with the following:

```
pick xf71a11 - last commit

pick 1a9ddqw - commit done with the wrong user
```

Change it like this:

```
pick xf71a11 - last commit

squash 1a9ddqw - commit done with the wrong user
```

*Very Important*: Remember with this action modifies the history of commits. It may lead to  inconsistency of the git history between developers who have pulled the history of commits prior to your changes.

Comment: Thank u for the reply but this wont work because I have merge commits in between. I’ve got an error trying this. Any other ideas ?